# Force cell format after setting value in ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have an interesting issue that I can't seem to figure out how to solve.

I need to export a date into excel in one format, but display it in another.

The user should see: ddMMMyyyy, but they enter it in MM/dd/yyyy. The problem I am having is that if I set the cell value to a MM/dd/yyyy format, it is not auto formatting to the ddMMMyyyy unless I manually edit the field in excel.

Is there any way to force the formatting?

```
worksheet.Cell("I" + rowIndex).SetValue<String>(LastUpdated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
worksheet.Cell("I" + rowIndex).Style.DateFormat.Format = "[$-409]dd-mmm-yyyy;@";
```